# I got PE file having having two ".data" sections Bytes of section name is different. What type of this file can be?

Tags: portable-executable

i got two PE files having same sections named as ".data". These name contains different bytes when we see in hex dump. This sections is having 00 bytes in contents. What is this file type can be?

Comment: you can suggest whether this file is malware or not?

Comment: Can't say whether it is malicious or not !!! The file might have been modified post compilation.Or the file might be corrupt as well.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.curlybrace.com/archive/PE%20File%20Structure.pdf

You can get all the details about section names here [PE file Structure]
And then decide yourself if the file is malicious or not.

Happy Overflowing :D

Comment: it seems Malicious to me though ;D

Answer (score 0):

Normal compilers shouldn't produce two sections with identical names, so the likely explanation is that the binary was modified post-compilation. Such obvious modifications are typical (but not conclusive) of malware. Without further information, it's not possible to say much else.